# How can I bold the fonts of a specific row or cell in an Excel worksheet with C#?

Tags: c#, windows, excel, datagridview

I am exporting data from a List<> to excel. I want to make some specific rows and cells bold. I need to make some cell merged also.

Below is the code I am using.

```
try
        {
            Excel.Application application;
            Excel.Workbook workBook;
            Excel.Worksheet workSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            application = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            workBook = application.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            int i = 1;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "MSS Close Sheet";                
            i++;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "MSS - " + dpsNoTextBox.Text;
            i++;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = customerNameTextBox.Text;
            i++;                
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Opening Date : ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = openingDateTextBox.Value.ToShortDateString();
            i++;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Closing Date : ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = closingDateTextBox.Value.ToShortDateString();
            i++;
            i++;
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 1] = "SL. No";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Month";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "Amount Deposited";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 4] = "Fine";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = "Cumulative Total";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = "Profit + Cumulative Total";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 7] = "Profit @ " + profitRateComboBox.Text;
            i++;



            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            foreach (RecurringDeposit rd in RecurringDepositList)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[i, 1] = rd.SN.ToString();
                workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = rd.MonthYear;
                workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = rd.InstallmentSize.ToString();
                workSheet.Cells[i, 4] = "";
                workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = rd.CumulativeTotal.ToString();
                workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = rd.ProfitCumulative.ToString();
                workSheet.Cells[i, 7] = rd.Profit.ToString();
                i++;
            }
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Total (" + RecurringDepositList.Count + " months installment)";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = totalAmountDepositedTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "a) Total Amount Deposited";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = totalAmountDepositedTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "b) Fine";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "";
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "c) Total Pft Paid";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = totalProfitPaidTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Sub Total";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = (totalAmountDepositedTextBox.Value + totalProfitPaidTextBox.Value).ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Deduction";
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "a) Excise Duty";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "0";
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "b) Income Tax on Pft. @ " + incomeTaxPercentageTextBox.Text;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "0";
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "c) Account Closing Charge ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = closingChargeCommaNumberTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "d) Outstanding on BAIM(FO) ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = baimFOLowerTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Total Deduction ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = (incomeTaxDeductionTextBox.Value + closingChargeCommaNumberTextBox.Value + baimFOTextBox.Value).ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Client Paid ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = customerPayableNumberTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "e) Current Balance ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = currentBalanceCommaNumberTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = "Exp. Pft paid on MSS A/C(PL67054)";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = plTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "e) Total Paid ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = customerPayableNumberTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = "IT on Pft (BDT16216)";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = incomeTaxDeductionTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Difference";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = (currentBalanceCommaNumberTextBox.Value - customerPayableNumberTextBox.Value).ToString("0.00");
            workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = "Account Closing Charge";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = closingChargeCommaNumberTextBox.Value;
            i++;

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            workBook.SaveAs("D:\\" + dpsNoTextBox.Text.Trim() + "-" + customerNameTextBox.Text.Trim() + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            workBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            application.Quit();

            releaseObject(workSheet);
            releaseObject(workBook);
            releaseObject(application);
```

[The sheet should look like this:](http://www.scribd.com/doc/182839719/mss-closed-pdf)

Answer (score 97):

How to **Bold** entire row 10 example:

```
workSheet.Cells[10, 1].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
```

---

More formally:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = workSheet.Cells[10, 1] as Xl.Range;
rng.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
```

---

How to **Bold** Specific Cell 'A10' for example:

```
workSheet.Cells[10, 1].Font.Bold = true;
```

---

Little more formal:

```
int row = 1;
int column = 1;  /// 1 = 'A' in Excel

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng = workSheet.Cells[row, column] as Xl.Range;
rng.Font.Bold = true;
```

Comment: It might be desirable to use the "UsedRange" property fo do some of the bolding: worksheet.UsedRange.Rows[1].Font.Bold = true;

Answer (score 10):

Your question is a little unclear...as the part that you indicate you want to bold in Excel is a DataGridView in the import from word method.  Do you maybe want to bold the first row in the excel document?

```
using xl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

xl.Range rng = (xl.Range)xlWorkSheet.Rows[0];
rng.Font.Bold = true;
```

Simple as that!

HTH,
Z

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. xlWorkSheet.Rows[0,0] is a 2d array.

Comment: You must return this `(xl.Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[0,0];`

Comment: Sorry for comment  3.5 years later, but this code works if I change `xl.Range rng = (xl.Range)` to be `Range rng = (Range)`

Answer (score 5):

I have done this in a project a long time ago. The code given below write a whole rows bold with specific column names and all of these columns are written in bold format.

```
private void WriteColumnHeaders(DataColumnCollection columnCollection, int row, int column)
    {
        // row represent particular row you want to bold its content.
        for (i = 0; i < columnCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            DataColumn col = columnCollection[i];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, column + i + 1] = col.Caption;
            // Some Font Styles
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, column + i + 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, column + i + 1].Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(192, 192, 192);
            //xlWorkSheet.Columns[i + 1].ColumnWidth = xlWorkSheet.Columns[i+1].ColumnWidth + 10;
        }
    }
```

You must pass value of row 0 so that first row of your excel sheets have column headers with bold font size. Just change `DataColumnCollection` to your columns name and change `col.Caption` to specific column name.

**Alternate**

You may do this to cell of excel sheet you want bold.

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[row, column].Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

this works for me, so try it :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range rng =(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)XcelApp.Cells[1, i];
rng.Font.Bold = true; 
rng.Interior.Color =System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
rng.BorderAround();
```

Comment: This works, but can you tell another way of giving the whole row or a column properties like this @MORFEE89

Answer (score 1):

I was using ClosedXML nuget and the most voted solution didn't work for me, instead I used the following and it worked perfectly fine

```
var currentRow = 1;
worksheet.Row(currentRow).Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

## To Bold a Range (sample cell values are given as A1 to G1)

```
$Range = $worksheet.Range("A1", "G1")
$Range.Font.Bold = $true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.Cell(1, 1).RichText.SetBold(true);
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

Below is the exact code you need to make your sheet look exactly as it is in the attached PDF:

```
try
        {
            Excel.Application application;
            Excel.Workbook workBook;
            Excel.Worksheet workSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            application = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
            workBook = application.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            int i = 1;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "MSS Close Sheet"; 
            WorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;               
            i++;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "MSS - " + dpsNoTextBox.Text;
            WorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            i++;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = customerNameTextBox.Text;
            i++;                
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Opening Date : ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = openingDateTextBox.Value.ToShortDateString();
            i++;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Closing Date : ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = closingDateTextBox.Value.ToShortDateString();
            i++;
            i++;
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 1] = "SL. No";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Month";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "Amount Deposited";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 4] = "Fine";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = "Cumulative Total";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = "Profit + Cumulative Total";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 7] = "Profit @ " + profitRateComboBox.Text;
            WorkSheet.Cells[i, 1].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
            i++;



            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            foreach (RecurringDeposit rd in RecurringDepositList)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[i, 1] = rd.SN.ToString();
                workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = rd.MonthYear;
                workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = rd.InstallmentSize.ToString();
                workSheet.Cells[i, 4] = "";
                workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = rd.CumulativeTotal.ToString();
                workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = rd.ProfitCumulative.ToString();
                workSheet.Cells[i, 7] = rd.Profit.ToString();
                i++;
            }
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Total (" + RecurringDepositList.Count + " months installment)";
            WorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = totalAmountDepositedTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "a) Total Amount Deposited";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = totalAmountDepositedTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "b) Fine";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "";
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "c) Total Pft Paid";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = totalProfitPaidTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Sub Total";
            WorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = (totalAmountDepositedTextBox.Value + totalProfitPaidTextBox.Value).ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Deduction";
            WorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "a) Excise Duty";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "0";
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "b) Income Tax on Pft. @ " + incomeTaxPercentageTextBox.Text;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = "0";
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "c) Account Closing Charge ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = closingChargeCommaNumberTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "d) Outstanding on BAIM(FO) ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = baimFOLowerTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Total Deduction ";
            WorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = (incomeTaxDeductionTextBox.Value + closingChargeCommaNumberTextBox.Value + baimFOTextBox.Value).ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Client Paid ";
            WorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = customerPayableNumberTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "e) Current Balance ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = currentBalanceCommaNumberTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = "Exp. Pft paid on MSS A/C(PL67054)";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = plTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "e) Total Paid ";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = customerPayableNumberTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = "IT on Pft (BDT16216)";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = incomeTaxDeductionTextBox.Value.ToString("0.00");
            i++;

            workSheet.Cells[i, 2] = "Difference";
            WorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            workSheet.Cells[i, 3] = (currentBalanceCommaNumberTextBox.Value - customerPayableNumberTextBox.Value).ToString("0.00");
            workSheet.Cells[i, 5] = "Account Closing Charge";
            workSheet.Cells[i, 6] = closingChargeCommaNumberTextBox.Value;
            i++;

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            workBook.SaveAs("D:\\" + dpsNoTextBox.Text.Trim() + "-" + customerNameTextBox.Text.Trim() + ".xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            workBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            application.Quit();

            releaseObject(workSheet);
            releaseObject(workBook);
            releaseObject(application);
```

Comment: Considering I used the macro recorder to make the sheet look exactly like the attached PDF you provided, I find that interesting.  I guess Excel can't write code that compiles properly?