# Make Bold Font in DataTable?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

I  add dynamic row in DataTable.I need to bold the "Total" in Bold.How to do this?

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", "Total", "valuehere"});
```

Comment: You are not going to display datatable,then why to make it bold,can you elaborate what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @Anand is right could you explain what do you want to do? You want in to display on a datagrid? Wpf/Forms? Some more code?

Comment: @Anand   my aim is I get the data in Datatable from sql.And I export the table into excel.In that excel sheet,I want to display total as bold font

Comment: Maybe try formatting the excel file? Never done it myself, but maybe something like: `Range("A:A").FontWeight = 700 'bold` would bold column A in Excel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187125/make-a-text-in-a-particular-cell-bold-in-exported-excel-sheet-windows-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Typically text formatting is done wherever the code for displaying the text is. A string does not contain that sort of formatting information usually.

Answer (score 0):

Carlos is right.

At the max you can try getting your text from database with  tag as follows, which might help you.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", "<b>Total", "<b>valuehere"});
```

You can bold the Object in which you are displaying this datatable values.

Eg. Label, gridviewcells,etc

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/406704/Export-DataTable-to-Excel-with-Formatting-in-Cshar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187125/make-a-text-in-a-particular-cell-bold-in-exported-excel-sheet-windows-c-sharp?answertab=active#tab-top