# Format Excel Columns from Angular

Tags: angular, excel, typescript, export-to-excel

I'm trying to bold the column titles from an excel worksheet, using the json_to_sheet function. How can i bold the ID,or format the first cell?

```
var ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([{ID:"ID"}], {header: ["ID"], skipHeader: true});
let excelFileName='Exported Serviceberichte';  
const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };  
const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });  
this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
```

**ID**

2

3

4

This is how it should look.

Answer (score 1):

How to Bold Specific Cell 'A1' for example:

```
workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Font.Bold = true;
```

More examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19883924/15439733

Comment: When I'm trying this in Angular, it says that the first 1('Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.'). When I get rid of the first one I get the error that 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 1)'. Is there a better way to do it in Typescript?